# Facebook api v2.11 doesn't return likes or reactions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[facebook Graph explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvWUI.png)
When I use 2.10 version of facebook API, I can get likes for the post. When I use 2.11 version of API I can't do this. I set all possible rights for access token, but it didn't help. I watched changelog for 2.11 version, but there were no words about this URL. What can be solution for this problem? How I can get likes for the post?

```
try {
    $response = $this->fb->get('/' . $page_id . '?fields=access_token', $this->access_token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    return;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying with an App Access Token. Try with a Page Token of the relevant Page instead, and likes/reactions will most likely show up. Check out the 90 days deprecation of v2.11, user data will only be in the result if you use a Page Token.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Of course you have to manage the Page in order to get a Page Token.

Comment: What is mean a page token? Can you give link on the description, please?

Comment: i added some links in the answer

Comment: But why I can't get access token from my code (I added it to the question) with using get method? I get request with id only, but without page access token. I don't want to authorize with redirecting to another page, as was presented in your second link.

Comment: do you own the page?

Comment: No, I try to get info from page that doesn't belong me.

Comment: you cannot get the info from a page you do not own, because you cannot get a page token from a page you do not own.

Comment: added that info to my answer.

Comment: Does it mean that there are no ways to get some info from API about user if you don't own the page?

Comment: why does [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) return all neccessary data without some problems?

Comment: no, there is no way. in the api explorer, you are probably not selecting YOUR app, but the api explorer app. for that one, the 90 days deprecation is still valid and it will work for some more weeks.

Comment: And what about public application? If I will create application and will publish it to facebook apps? Will the application have necessary permissions to get info about users?

Comment: it does not matter, it really is not possible in any way if you do not own the page. if it is not your page, the like data is not available. why would you need the user data anyway, if it is not even your page?

Comment: For example I want to get ids of users, that liked some post, and get their country or city position. But if you said that it is not possible to get any info about page, that I don't manage, I can ever hardly get what I want above.

Comment: you cannot even get their country/city if you manage the page. that is what page insights are for - but you cannot get access to those either if you do not manage the page.

Comment: Thanks, @luschn, for answers!